# Limiting GTM Code Functionality on Website: Hiding Dimensions and Events from External Agency

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I have a website for ordering a product, which involves a four-step process. I've been tasked with integrating a GTM (Google Tag Manager) code from an external agency, and I already have a snippet of the code for this purpose.

However, I want to limit the agency's ability to freely inject JavaScript code, so I'm looking to restrict its functionality from my site's code level. I know I can add a condition to only send events to GA4 (Google Analytics 4), but can I override the events?

To be more specific, I want to:

Hide all the custom dimensions I'm using.
Conceal or override the time clients spend on individual pages.
Prevent the addition of conversion events to a button on my site.
In essence, I'd like the agency to only see the number of clients on the site and their navigation between pages (a basic funnel devoid of additional data).

Is this achievable through the site's code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: GTM's permissions aren't that robust. The best you could do would be to remove their publish rights. However, they will still be able to see all the contents of the container. If you want to limit everything they see, you might be able to deploy two separate GTM containers; one for you and one for the agency. But that seems like overkill and a pain to manage and oversee.